# question about blocking i/o in a thread

Tags: linux, pthreads

I'm using pthreads on Linux, and one of my threads periodically calls the write function on a device file descriptor.  If the write call takes a while to finish, will my thread be suspended so other threads can run?  I didn't set any of the scheduling features of pthreads, so my question is about default thread behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as nothing else is trying to write to the same resource, the other threads should run while the writing thread waits for its write to complete.

Comment: This seems to make sense, but I couldn't find any documentation that describes default scheduling behavior for pthreads.

Comment: I found this to be an interesting read: http://www.icir.org/gregor/tools/pthread-scheduling.html

Answer (score 3):

If a `write()` call blocks, only the calling thread is suspended.  This is documented in the [POSIX spec for `write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> If there is enough space for all the
>   data requested to be written
>   immediately, the implementation should
>   do so. Otherwise, the calling thread
>   may block; that is, pause until enough
>   space is available for writing.

Note that it says calling *thread*, not calling *process*.

Answer (score 1):

See if blocking behavior is explicitly defined here 
http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/nptl-design.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In principle, YES, other threads can run.

But be aware that some filesystems have locking mechnisms which permit only one concurrent IO operation on a single file. So if another thread does another IO on the same file (even if it's via a different file descriptor) it MAY block it for some of the duration of the write() system call.

There are also other in-kernel locks for other facililties. Most of them will not block other threads running unless they're doing closely related activities, however.

Answer (score 0):

If your device file descriptor is a shared resource, you have to take care of locking. But once it's thread-safe, calls to such shared resource are serialized, thus if one thread writes, the rest are blocked. If locking is not implemented, the data may be garbled.

Comment: My file descriptor isn't shared, it's specific to one thread.  If that thread takes a long time to finish, will it be scheduled out?

Comment: If each thread has its own file descriptor then there is no contention so there is no reason for other threads to be blocked. However your question states there IS A file descriptor and there ARE several threads, so I assumed the file descriptor was shared.

Comment: It's not a question about contention.  The question is if one thread takes a long time to complete a write to a file descriptor, how do other threads get scheduled in.

Comment: As long as each thread has the same priority, the OS should schedule them appropriately regardless how long it take for an individual thread to do the job. They all should get time slices as necessary. Otherwise it will cause thread starvation, which is a known and solved problem. I can't go into specifics of how pthreads are scheduled though but I am sure the OS is effective in dealing with thread starvation.